# How do I convert javascript object to string?

Tags: javascript

I have the following json:

```
{
'a':'vala',
'b':'valb'
}
```

I want to convert this to a string:

```
"a=vala,b=valb"
```

What is the best way to get there?

Comment: Simple loop over the object?

Comment: Im a python guy, no array.join() type magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the keys, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the results to format the string, and finally [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) using a comma separator.

```
var item = {
  'a':'vala',
  'b':'valb'
};

var result = Object.keys(item).map(function(key) {
    return key + '=' + item[key];
}).join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
'a':'vala',
'b':'valb'
};

var str = '';
for (var key in obj) {
   if (str.length != 0) str += ',';
   str += key+'='+obj[key];
}

alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it--all it takes is a simple for in loop on the object with some formatting for your results:

```
var obj = {
  'a':'vala',
  'b':'valb'
};

function translate(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    result.push(key + '=' + obj[key]);
  }  
  return result.join(',')
}

console.log(translate(obj));
```